# DocuSign Bulk Send Hidden Fields Possible?

Tags: docusignapi

I'm trying to send a document to many people through bulk send but need to send some data along with each document that is hidden from the recipient.  The hidden data for each recipient is different.  I tried setting the tabs width and height to zero but it still displays the value when the recipient views the document.

**Test Tab Settings**

```
        payeeIdTab.TabLabel = "PayeeID";
        payeeIdTab.RecipientId = signer.RecipientId;
        payeeIdTab.YPosition = "0";
        payeeIdTab.XPosition = "0";
        payeeIdTab.PageNumber = "1";
        payeeIdTab.Height = 0;
        payeeIdTab.Width = 0;
        payeeIdTab.Required = "false";
        payeeIdTab.DisableAutoSize = "true";
        payeeIdTab.Locked = "true";
        payeeIdTab.DocumentId = template.Documents.First().DocumentId;
```

Comment: As a last resort, have you tried making the font color white? So basically white text on a white document.

Answer (score 2):

If you were just sending one Envelope at a time (i.e., not using Bulk Send), I would suggest that you use Recipient **customFields** to store the data (i.e., instead of using tabs). Recipient **customFields** allow you to associate certain data with each Envelope Recipient that the recipients won't see (i.e., data won't be visible in the document anywhere) but that you can access programmatically at a later time. The **customFields** property of a Recipient is [defined as](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipients/) follows:

[image]

As described above, the JSON looks like this (as a top-level attribute of a **recipient** object):

```
"customFields": {
    "sample string 1",
    "sample string 2"
}
```

That all being said though -- unfortunately it doesn't appear that "Bulk Send" currently supports being able to specify **customFields** for ***Recipients*** (as described above). If that's true, you might consider sending envelopes one at a time via API (so that you can specify custom metadata for each Recipient by using **customFields**), instead of using the "Bulk Send" approach. Keep in mind the API limits though. e.g., if you're sending Envelopes to just 10 people, sending 10 separate "Create Envelope" API requests would probably be feasible -- but if you're sending Envelopes to 100 people, then using 100 separate "Create Envelope" API requests is much less appealing.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Your solution is known but would bring other problems to the table.  I need to be able to send 30,000+ documents in a day.  With bulk send this can be done pretty easily but won't allow attaching of customFields.  I may have to get in touch with DocuSign.